# Ext.draw.sprite event not triggering

Tags: java, javascript, extjs

I have created a sprite item on a chart in Extjs 4.2 and I want to catch the mouse events of the sprite item. But I am not getting the events.
Any Idea ?

```
var redcircle = Ext.create('Ext.draw.Sprite', {
    type: 'circle',
    radius: 10,
    fill: '#f00',        
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    listeners: {
        'mouseover': function (args) {
            alert('Mouse over')
        }
    },
    group: 'circles',
    surface: surface
}).show(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done a example it is working at my end

```
 Ext.onReady(function () {
      Ext.create('Ext.draw.Component', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    items: [{
        type: 'circle',
        radius: 90,
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        fill: 'blue',
        listeners:{
           mouseover:function( e, t, eOpts ){
           alert("Mouse Over");
           }
        }
    }]
});
 });
```

Comment: Hi Surya, your example is perfect but I am creating a sprite item on chart surface after chart rendering, The item is visible but somehow I am not able get the events.

Comment: Could you please provide me the code,I can have a look at me end.